# How to call Solidity contract function in node.js only after the contract has been deployed?

Tags: solidity, nodejs

Would like to call the deployedContract.changeFirstName function only after the deployedContract is complete because deployedContract is an asynchronous function. What would be the best way to do that?

```
    //creating a new instance of contract, this is an async call - hence the need to wait. Otherwise VM-ware invalid op$ deployedContract = IDLedgerContract.new([],{data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000},
    (err, contract) =>
    {
    if (contract.address !== undefined)
            console.log('Sample contract address has been defined: ' + contract.address)

    } );

    //deployedContract.changeFirstName('test', {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}) //This needs to happen after the deployedContract has been deployed
```